# Get the superclass of an anonymous or inner class

Tags: java

How to get the superclass of an anonymous class:

```
 Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
 };
```

This prints `java.lang.Object`. Because `getClass()` returns `EnclosingClass$1`.

```
System.out.println(r.getClass()); // class test.ClassTest$1
System.out.println(r.getClass().getSuperclass()); // class java.lang.Object
System.out.println(Runnable.class.isAssignableFrom(r.getClass())); // true
System.out.println(Runnable.class.isInstance(r)); // true
```

(All these methods are native)

So is there any way to get the superclass of the anonymous class? It seems this is known at runtime. For the above example I want to obtain `Runnable`. Same goes for inner classes by the way - if you define `class Foo implements Runnable` I don't see a way to obtain `Runnable`

The reason why this is important is that some frameworks may rely on `getClass().getSuperclass()` and it may appear that you should be careful when using anonymous and inner classes.

Comment: Runnable is an interface, not a class, there might be many, try the same with Thread.

Comment: `getInterfaces()[0]` indeed gives `java.lang.Runnable`.

Comment: blah.. look who should be going to sleep..

Comment: sorry for closing the question, but it really doesn't contribute anything.

Comment: For those, who have googled the header, as I did: `instance.getClass().getSuperclass()` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For this case, Runnable is an interface which can be gotten via [getInterfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29). In cases where anonymous classes extend a base class `getSuperclass()` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The super class *is* `java.lang.Object`. All objects extend `Object` by default.

`Runnable` is an interface. You won't see it in the implementation hierarchy, regardless of the subject of the call (normal class, inner class, anonymous inner class).

Can you explain why you think `Runnable` should be visible in the implementation hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Runnable is an interface, not a class. You will get the same result for a real class that implements Runnable (or other interface) and doesn't extend any class.

The following code will print `class java.lang.Thread`:

```
     Thread r = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getSuperclass());
        }
     };
     r.start();
```